$S : E → E$ by $S(x) = x − 2\phi(x)y_0$. Define a norm on $E$ by $||x||_\phi := ||Sx||$. Show that $|| · ||_\phi$ cannot be equivalent to $|| · ||$.
Let $(E, || · ||)$ be a normed linear space and $\phi$ a linear functional on $E$
which is not continuous. Let $y_0 ∈ E$ be such that $\phi(y_0) = 1$.
Define
$S : E → E$ by
$S(x) = x − 2\phi(x)y_0$.
Define a new norm on $E$ by $||x||_\phi := ||Sx||$.

(a). Show that $S
^2 = I$, the identity operator on E.


(b). Show that there is a linear isomorphism $T : E → E$ such that
$||T(x)||_\phi = ||x||$ for all $x \in E$.


(c). Show that $|| · ||_\phi$ cannot be equivalent to $|| · ||$.

My Efforts
To prove (a) I can write for all $x\in E$ there exist $n\in \mathcal{N}(\phi)$ such that $$x=n+\phi(x) y_0$$ where  $\mathcal{N}(\phi)$ is null space of $\phi$.
This gives $\phi (x) y_0=x-n$ and
$$S(x)=x-2(x-n)=2n-x.$$
Hence $$S^2(x)=2n-S(x)=x.$$
This proves part (a).
To prove part (b), put $S=T$.
Are my solutions to (a) and (b) correct? Using (a) and (b) I have to show (c).
But I am stuck here. Any hints??

As some general advice, for part (a) you rather want to fix some $x\in E$ and work with this choice $x$ rather than varying over all elements of $E$ simultaneously. This is quite significant as your choice of $n$ depends on the choice of $x$. It may also be a good idea to expand on why there is some $n\in\mathcal{N}(\phi )$ with the desired properties. I suspect you need to use the assumption $\phi (y_{0})=1$ here. The rest of what you have done so far looks good.

Ok I will expand it

You arguments are fine. For part c), note that you haven't used that $\phi$ is unbounded. The fact that $\phi$ is unbounded implies that there exists a sequence $\{x_n\}$ such that $x_n\to0$ and $\phi(x_n)\to\infty$. Then
$$
\|x_n\|_\phi=\|Sx_n\|\geq\|\phi(x_n)y_0\|-\|x_n\|=\phi(x_n)\|y_0\|-\|x_n\|\to\infty,
$$
while $\|x_n\|\to0$. So the norms are not equivalent.
